# Monitor not idling after i3wm installation

Tags: 14.04, unity, multiple-monitors, i3-wm

Yesterday I installed i3wm and noticed that after the screensaver turns on, the screens turns black, but the monitors stay on (have two of them).

Up to now I was using Unity and the session locked and turned the monitors off after a set amount of time of idling.

What do I need to do to make them behave like this again?

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ1aw.jpg) is what happens when using `gnome-screensaver-command -l`

Here's the output of `xset q`:

```
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  660    repeat rate:  25
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fadfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  600    cycle:  600
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x20    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

Comment: Can you please add the output of `xset q`?

Comment: Yes, added it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The the timeout values for all power saving features (*Standby*, *Suspend* and *Off*) are set to `0`, which disables them.

You can set the timeouts with the `xset` command:

```
xset dpms [standby [suspend [off]]]
```

Where `standby`, `suspend` and `off` are the timeout values in seconds. For most modern displays there is (at least in my experience) no real difference between those modes. So if you set

```
xset dpms 0 0 600
```

it will turn off your display after 10 minutes of idling.

You can just add this as an `exec` configuration to your `~/.i3/config`:

```
exec --no-startup-id xset dpms 0 0 600
```

---

If you want to immediately turn of your screen, you can do so with

```
xset dmps force off
```

Comment: Damn, seems like I was missing the dpms keyword in that command! This seems to be working, thanks!